# How to find the largest path sum in a triangle of numbers

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to write a program to find the largest path sum of a triangle. A path sum is sum of numbers that appear on the paths starting from the top towards the base, so that on each path the next number is located directly below or below-and-one-place-to-the-right like below:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

I saw an algorithm on the internet that solves this problem, but the output remains as the original value of array index `[0][0]`.

Here's my code in C language:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int rows,testcases;
    scanf("%d",&testcases);
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    int a[rows][rows];
    while(testcases--){
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i+1;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }

        for(int i=rows;i>1;i--){
            for(int j=0;j<i-1;j++){
                if(a[i][j]>a[i][j+1]){
                    a[i-1][j]=a[i-1][j]+a[i][j];
                }
                else{
                    a[i-1][j]=a[i-1][j]+a[i][j+1];
                }
            }
       }

        printf("The Largest Path Sum = %d",a[0][0]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I expected that array index 0 = the largest sum.
The actual result is the original value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bottom up dynamic programming solution. Your loop conditions are incorrect. Iterate the outer loop from `rows - 1` to `1` and inner loop from `0` to `i-1`.

The solution then looks as follows:

```
for(int i = rows - 1;i > 0;i--){
  for(int j = 0;j < i;j++){
    if(a[i][j] > a[i][j+1]){
      a[i-1][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j];
    }
    else {
      a[i-1][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j+1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You So Much...
It Worked.